# Regex: Duration (hours, minutes) in dart

Tags: regex, dart

I'm trying to sort a list of data using RegEx. Currently, the code below only checks for hours and minutes.

Example of the output currently:

> 1:22:00.000000

But I have some data that will also have just minutes  or just hours.

I'm looking to edit this code so it will check for all those possibilities:

> - Hours
> - Minutes
> - Hours and Minutes

```
final _regExp = RegExp(r'(?<hours>\d+)h (?<minutes>\d+)m');
Duration _parseDuration(String line) {
  final match = _regExp.firstMatch(line);

  if (match == null) {
    throw Exception('Could not get duration from: $line');
  }

  return Duration(
      hours: int.parse(match.namedGroup('hours')),
      minutes: int.parse(match.namedGroup('minutes')));
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the different forms you input can have and what the result you expect it to be. It is difficult to make a solid solution without some test data. :)

Comment: Not sure if you can use the same name for the capturing group, but you could use an alternation `(?:(?:(\d+)h )?(\d+)m|(?:(\d+)h))` https://regex101.com/r/uSn0sL/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can use the same name for the capturing group, but you could use an alternation to match optional hours and minutes or hours.

```
(?:(?:(\d+)h )?(\d+)m|(\d+)h)
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:(\d+)h )?` Capture **group 1**, match optional digits and `h`
  - `(\d+)m` Capture **group 2**, Match 1+ digits and `m`
  - `|` Or
  - `(\d+)h` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ digits and `h`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TEKjmj/1/) | [Dart demo](https://tio.run/##bVBBasMwEDwnrxhMIRItxrFvCcGHNsde2mshmEi2BZZkZKkNtHm7aylO6wQLIXZXMzvDsMLYvv/UgkEWQhGK7@WiFKpocDC82p9a7PAWCmJWJN/4@8EeaQ2ah0L@XHq6otvl4sWZwgqtcGgL0/FrS96tEapCIxQPEsBFRBb2WA8So1hcCtPZVz8kAbtdeqwoQUbkDso1zbgDsLXRX9ifjrwNOqtn7RoGpS0qbsGudkqj5QYPfmfwCZz9M9ryDsL@uDLatWRNkec3kyxMoiSJthOevOOlE1Qwbrh1RuEvhotpoNbOdBsIZeOQE6np0/VPCuUsv/mV1Hs@T@Jlax/abcZRltRIExl5cDsYtISthxrj@Sen8@QpMZ0lZjPEO8VsqM99/ws)

The hours are in group 1 or 3, the minutes in group 2.

I am not familiar with Dart so there probably is a better way to write it, but for the idea I have added an example.

```
final _regExp = RegExp(r'(?:(?:(\d+)h )?(\d+)m|(\d+)h)');
Duration _parseDuration(String line) {
  final match = _regExp.firstMatch(line);

  if (match == null) {
    throw Exception('Could not get duration from: $line');
  }
  String h = match.group(1) ?? match.group(3) ?? "00";
  String m = match.group(2) ?? "00";


  return Duration(
      hours: int.parse(h),
      minutes: int.parse(m));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would work. I just added so each group is optional and if any group is not in the input, then use the value 0:

```
void main() {
  print(_parseDuration('5h'));      // 5:00:00.000000
  print(_parseDuration('5m'));      // 0:05:00.000000
  print(_parseDuration('10h 50m')); // 10:50:00.000000
}

final _regExp = RegExp(r'((?<hours>\d+)h)?[ ]*((?<minutes>\d+)m)?');
Duration _parseDuration(String line) {
  final match = _regExp.firstMatch(line);

  if (match == null) {
    throw Exception('Could not get duration from: $line');
  }

  return Duration(
      hours: int.parse(match.namedGroup('hours') ?? '0'),
      minutes: int.parse(match.namedGroup('minutes') ?? '0'));
}
```